# Perl regexp /(\r\n|\r|\n)/

Tags: regex, pcre

I want to know how this ambiguous pattern is solved in perl(more generally everything that use libpcre):

```
/(\r\n|\r|\n)/
```

When the pattern sees `\r\n` will it match one time or twice?
And what is the rules face to this situation?

Thanks

Comment: the best answer would be to test it.

Comment: @Chad, You are write (actually I knew it match only once) but I want to know why, what is the logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It will match `\r\n` once because Perl uses a regex-directed engine which evaluates alternations eagerly. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/engine.html).

> You can easily find out whether the regex flavor you intend to use has a text-directed or regex-directed engine. If backreferences and/or lazy quantifiers are available, you can be certain the engine is regex-directed. You can do the test by applying the regex `regex|regex not` to the string `regex not`. If the resulting match is only `regex`, the engine is regex-directed. If the result is `regex not`, then it is text-directed. The reason behind this is that the regex-directed engine is "eager".

Comment: If I understand correctly it mean the /(\r|\r\n|\n)/ have an other meaning.

Comment: Yes, `/(\r|\r\n|\n)/` would match `\r`, then `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

It will try and match the pipe-separated alternatives in order from left to right. Thus the first alternative will match the entire string `"\r\n"`, and there will only be one match. There's no ambiguity here.

Answer (score 1):

> ...perl (more generally everything that use libpcre)

Possible misconception here: Perl does not "use libpcre".  The PCRE library is a separate project that came along *after* Perl, and mimics much of Perl's regex functionality.  PHP and ActionScript use libpcre, but most "Perl-derived" flavors (like Python, Java, and .NET) implement their regex support natively.

But they all share the trait in question here: they settle for the first alternative that works, rather than hold out for the longest match as a text-directed engine would.

Answer (score 0):

It'll match it once.  More here: http://technocage.com/~caskey/dos2unix/